# Python Highest Card Game using imported Modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, module

So i Have created a Highest Card Game in Python and I am looking to add a feature but I am struggling with the code. So I want to add a feature where a draw is not possible, so if two players draw the same Card, they then have to draw another card to see who wins. Sort of like a tie Breaker. New to Python and would really appreciate the help.

## The Highest Card game, for up to 2 - 7 players

```
import Cards, Games

class HC_Card(Cards.Card):
    @property
    def value(self):
        val = HC_Card.CARDS.index(self.card) + 1
        return val

class HC_Deck(Cards.Deck):
    def populate(self):
        for suit in HC_Card.SUITS:
            for card in HC_Card.CARDS:
                self.cards.append(HC_Card(card, suit))

class HC_Hand(Cards.Hand):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(HC_Hand, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        rep = self.name + ": " + super(HC_Hand, self).__str__()
        return rep
    @property
    def total(self):
        t = 0
        for card in self.cards:
            t += card.value
        return t
 
class HC_Game(object):
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.players = []
        for name in names:
            player = HC_Hand(name)
            self.players.append(player)
        self.deck = HC_Deck()
        self.deck.populate()
        self.deck.shuffle()
    
    def play(self):
        self.deck.deal(self.players, per_hand = 1)
        highestCard = 0
        highestName = ""
        for player in self.players:
            print(player)
            if player.total == highestCard:
                highestName = "Draw"
            elif player.total > highestCard:
                highestCard = player.total
                highestName = player.name
        print("\nAnd the winner is...", highestName, "With the..", , "\b.")
        
        
        for player in self.players:
            player.clear()
 
def main():
    print("\nThis is the Highest Card game...")
    print("The player with the Highest card wins.. Good Luck!\n")
    names = []
    number = Games.askForNumber("How many players? (2-7): ", low = 2, high = 8)
    print()
    i = 1
    for i in range(number):
        name = input("Enter player name: ")
        if name == "":
            names.append("Anon")
            print()
            i += 1
        else:
            names.append(name)
            print()
            #i += 1
    game = HC_Game(names)
    again = "Y"
    rounds = 0
    while again == "y" or again == "Y":
        rounds += 1
        num_cards_dealt = number * rounds
        if num_cards_dealt > 52 - number:
            game.__init__(names)
            rounds = 0
        game.play()
        again = Games.askYesNo("\nDo you want to play again? ")
        print()
    print("I hope you enjoyed the game..")
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-think your `play()` section of code a bit.  You are on the right track.  It may help to draw a little pencil & paper flow chart, which will help you code the logic loop.  Here are a couple things to think through:

1. You won't know if there is a tie until the highest card is established, so remove the code that identifies the players in your first loop.
2. So, what if 4 players all draw the same card?  Well, after we establish what the high card is, then we can loop over the players again and *make a new list* of the ones with the card.
3. Then what?  we need to draw again for just the folks in the new collection.
4. What could happen then (same as before)?  Well, 1 player could be identified with the highest card, or maybe 2 are tied again...  That sounds like the control logic of a `while` loop, right?  `while len(players with winning card) > 1: do another round`....

So, what is above should describe a general approach for a beginner program.  There needs to be a loop because we don't know how many draws it will take to resolve ties.  There needs to be a new container (a `list` is fine) that we can build (most easily with another tiny loop inside the outer loop) to hold the round's winners.

Give that a try, comment back and edit your question with any attempts made if you are stuck!

Comment: Thank you for your time. I shall have a look and see what I can figure out.